# is it good to delete original data if data has been indexed into elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture

Hi i'm new to elasticsearch.

Recently, I'm trying to design search engine platform.

One thing that is really confusing me is storage of elasticsearch.

as far as i know, once document has been indexed, user can find contents of data from elasticsearch.

1. does it mean that I can delete original document files? because users can get data from elasticsearch.
2. Or Do I have to store original data somewhere?
3. Or it depends on use cases?

Please help me.

Comment: It depends, as always, on the use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hoping you are using RDBMS or some other robust data store for your application and using elasticsearch to improve the search or read performance, Elasticsearch is not a database while database should be robust.

Please refer [robustness section of elasticsearch official blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql#robustness) where they clearly mention its not as robust as typical databases and there are a lot of out of memory errors and its build for speed considering you have ample amount of memory.

In-short, you should not delete the original data ie if you can't afford the data-loss in your application as data-loss happens in ES.

Comment: At the same time, that article dates back in 2013 and OOM are not that big of a problem as they used to be. [Much work](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html) has been done to improve this and many other aspects.

Comment: Overstated -- the op said that this is a search-engine but that's all. There are some use-cases where only the index is needed and to store the original data would be pointless and expensive. A search engine where the indexes are constantly refreshed from scanning the web would be a good example. Not wrong, just overstated, though your last sentence does help I don't feel it adds enough balance.